# can we have Webrtc2sip installed in debian?

Tags: debian, webrtc

I want to implement a webrtc application that wiil be able to make calls over VoIP but I'm stuck! I don't et any sound in the tow sides! I found that webrct2sip may solve this problem but I can'tinstall it on m debain!!!

Can we install Webrtc2sip in a debian machine??

Answer (score 0):

I installed it on my Ubuntu machine, which is debian based. 
Maybe this will help you

http://linux.autostatic.com/installing-webrtc2sip-on-ubuntu-1204